# Outlook '16 Calendaring Macros/Rules -- filtering calendar invites for three different people

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, calendar, email-filter, productivity

I support calendaring (Outlook 2016 on WIN10) multiple directors as an EA through an MS Exchange Server. I would love to create a rule or Macro to filter incoming meeting invitations based on who it is received for, and filter into a sub-folder of the inbox (ie invites for Bob, invites for Alice...)

Right now I am using a rule applying to all meeting invitations to move the email from the inbox to a general meeting invitations folder, but it doesn't organize the meeting invites by which VP I am receiving it for.

I can't seem to find anything on Rules which lets me apply the rule only to the folder I am currently in, and also anything which lets me filter by who I am receiving the invitation for (only delineating which name is in the To: box, cc, etc)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it helps, I am receiving the invites as an Outlook delegate for the users I am supporting.

Comment: Can you make your rule differentiate between VPs based on whether or not they are in the `Required Attendees`? That might not work if several of them are on the same invite though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/819c72db-25f6-4591-bbb8-d62b096686eb/outlook-need-to-filter-out-calendar-notifications-received-on-someone-elses-behalf?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy) toward the bottom of the thread.  The concept is to open the message properties for a message you received as a delegate and look for a string similar to "X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: JohnDoe@ExampleCompany.com" then base your rule on finding that string in the Message Headers.